# Working with model-driven form and validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am having form control like this:

```
<div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="!orderForm.controls.persons.controls[0].controls.firstName.valid && orderForm.controls.persons.controls[0].controls.firstName.touched" [formGroupName]="0">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" required />
</div>
```

Is there easier and shorter way to set the has-error class, since `[class.has-error]="!orderForm.controls.persons.controls[0].controls.firstName.valid && orderForm.controls.persons.controls[0].controls.firstName.touched` is way too long?

The component is defined like this:

```
   @Component({
        moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'order-form',
        templateUrl: 'order-form.component.html'
    })
    export class OrderFormComponent implements OnInit {
        orderForm: FormGroup;
        visitorsType: FormControl;
        startDate: FormControl;
        endDate: FormControl;
        persons: FormArray;
        duration: FormControl;
...
```

And form initialization is like this:

```
    ...
    constructor(private _quotesService: QuotesService, 
                private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {

            this.persons = this._formBuilder.array([]);

            this.orderForm = this._formBuilder.group({
                persons: this.persons,
            });

            (<FormArray>this.orderForm.controls['persons']).push(this.initVisitor(this.startDate.value));

            this.activate();
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular2 adds some CSS classes on its own. The one you are looking for is ng-invalid. If validator connected to your Control in the model will return false, this class will be added. You don't need to use your own "has-error" class.

Comment: Hi Celebes, yes I know that angular sets ng-valid, ng-invalid classes. The point is that I am using bootstrap for styling and it require to have has-error class to form-group in order to style it correctly.

Comment: Please post your Component code in the question too. You should be able to assign your controls to variables and use them, for example: `var firstNameControl = orderForm.controls.persons.controls[0].controls.firstName` and then use `firstNameControl .touched`, but your chain of execution seems weird and too long for me. Better yet encapsulate whole logic in some method like `[class.has-error]="firstNameHasError()"`